# How to pass render props to `children` prop in React using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to pass an `open` boolean prop from a wrapper `<Parent>` component to wrapped `children` component.

I am trying to create an `<Accordion open={true}>` component and want the open prop to be passed down from `<Accordion>` to `<AccordionContent>`.

I can't get the types (and possibly the render props pattern) right.

`App.tsx`

```
const App = () => {
      <Accordion open={true}>
        <AccordionTitle title="First Accordion" />
        <AccordionContent>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
        </AccordionContent>
      </Accordion>
}
```

`Accordion.tsx`

```
interface RenderPropTypes {
  isOpen: boolean;
}

interface AccordionProps {
  open?: boolean;
  children: ({isOpen}: RenderPropTypes) => React.ReactNode; // What should the type be here?
}

const Accordion = ({ open = false, children }: AccordionProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col border border-gray-600">
      {({isOpen}: RenderPropTypes) => (children(isOpen))} // Want to pass the open param/prop down to children ie <AccordionContent> with correct TS typings
    </div>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kcs53j?file=src%2FApp.tsx) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
const Accordion => (props: PropsWithChildren<{
    open: boolean
}>) => {
    // ... your code
    // You can use props.open
    return props.children;
};

const AccordionContent => (props: PropsWithChildren<{
    open: boolean
}>) => {
    return props.children;
};

const App = () => {
    const isOpen = useState(true);
    return (<Accordion open={isOpen}>
        <>
            <AccordionTitle title="First Accordion" />
            <AccordionContent open={isOpen}>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
            </AccordionContent >
        </>
    </Accordion>)
};
```